# How model process the number of samples(sequentially or parallelly) for an individual batch while training?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

For training model, if I am using 5 batches with batch_size=10, what I want to ask is that for a individual batch that get into the keras.fit, how actually model process the 10 samples, is it sequentially or parallelly?

And if the model process the samples sequentially then why I get memory exhausted error while increasing the batch size(set of images)?

I am using pre-trained model for street2shop problem. Any answer or reference will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the processing is in parallel, specially if using a GPU, that's how large speedups are produced. This is also the reason why you can get an out of memory situation, as it requires more memory. Try decreasing your batch size further, but it also depends on how big is the model and how much RAM is in your GPU.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it also parallel in case of CPU(because it also gives memory error) or is there something else? It will be great if you could provide me any reference.

Comment: @RahulAnand Yes also in CPU, but in CPU you have more memory available (the system RAM).